# Регулярные выражения: поиск подстроки если после неё нет определённого выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть следующее регулярное выражение:
`(?:\d+[-, \.]*)+\s*(?:нед|н)?[\. ]*`, оно применяется к строке: `3-4 нед. Математический анализ 1 гр`

При поиске подстроки находится 2 результата: `3-4 нед.`  и `1`  (часть от "1 гр"). Я бы хотел узнать, как мне искать подстроку таким образом, чтобы оно находило **только ту часть, после которой не идёт выражение** `(подгруппа|подгруп|подгр|п\/г|группа|гр)`?

Я пробовал использовать Negative Lookahead:

```
(?:\d+[-, \.]*)+\s*(?:нед|н)?[\. ]*(?!.*(подгруппа|подгруп|подгр|п\/г|группа|гр))
```

но при данном выражении у меня при совпадении с 'гр' все другие совпадения тоже становятся ненайденными, а если в нём убрать поиск всех символов в начале (`.*`), то оно вообще почему-то перестаёт работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `.*` нужно использовать только такой шаблон, который может встретиться до исключаемых слов.

Вы можете использовать

```py
\d+(?:[-,\s.]\d+)*\s*н(?:ед)?(?![.\s]*(?:подгруппа|подгруп|подгр|п\/г|группа|гр))[.\s]*
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/GYFy3c/1/). *Подробности*:

- `\d+` - одна или более цифр
- `(?:[-,\s.]\d+)*` - ноль и более последовательности `-`, `,` .` или пробельного символа, за которым следует одна или более цифр
- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `н` - буква `н`
- `(?:ед)?` - опциональная подстрока `ед`
- `(?![.\s]*(?:подгруппа|подгруп|подгр|п/г|группа|гр))` - сразу справа не должно быть ноля и более точек и пробельных символов, после которых идёт `подгруппа`, `подгруп`, `подгр`, `п/г`, `группа` и `гр`
- `[.\s]*` - ноль и более пробельных символов и точек.